# Can we see our last message in rooms we have not participated?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I have noticed that I cannot see my last message with the button load to my last message<kbd>load to my last message</kbd> load to my last message in rooms I don't participate/haven't participated just because this doesn't exist. This might be useful when a Room Owner (RO) moves a message from one room to another.

I know that I can see all of my most recent messages in the page https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/UserId/?tab=recent, but what happens if I want to continuously want my last message? Sure, replacing continuously numbers in URL https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/UserId/?tab=recent&page=n doesn't look very promising as I may be active in chat, but I last chatted in the room I want to search for 1 month ago.

Comment: Do know that the [recent](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep?tab=recent&page=2) tab supports pagination but not by means of the UI. You have to fiddle with the url and add `&page=2` yourself.

Comment: @rene good to know thanks! However, it would be great if this could be implemented in a chat room.

Comment: Why would/should the chat room display a message from a different room? that's illogical.

Comment: @KevinB not sure what you mean. If one of my messages is moved to a room I don't have the permission to talk, how can I see my last message? The button there doesn't exist.

Comment: That message is no longer part of the current room. It's as if it was never posted there.

Comment: @KevinB still can't understand. Is this affecting anything about my request?

Comment: well, yes. The function of that button is to load recent messages up until a recent message that you posted *in that room.* If you have no messages remaining in that room, that button isn't going to display said non-existent message.